# Javascript: how do you use multiple if else statments refering to different elements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, element, queryselector

I am Completely new to JavaScript so this may be really obvious but I am trying to build an Andon system using traffic lights where if the number is above or below a certain number the light will change colour (i.e. > 5 = green). There are nine sets of lights in total, I have successfully made one light change based on the variable by using query select all and then change the opacity.

When i try and do this with the second light nothing happens. I have tried to make it work by naming my div elements in html and CSS differently e.g. "Zcircle", "A1circle"

[Link](https://codepen.io/JH-KBRS/pen/yLNwGbW) to code pen.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Code

**HTML:**

```
div class="Zcontainer">
       <div class="Zcircle red" color="red">
       </div>
       <div class="Zcircle yellow" color="yellow"></div>
       <div class="Zcircle green" color="green"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="A1container">
       <div class="A1Circle red" color="red">
       </div>
       <div class="A1Circle yellow" color="yellow"></div>
       <div class="A1Circle green" color="green"></div>
     </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.Zcontainer {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  border-radius: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: relative;
  left: 250px;
  bottom: 75px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 70px;
}

.Zcircle {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.Zcircle::after {
  border-right: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  border-radius: 100%;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.Zcircle.red {
  background-color: #c0392b;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px #c0392b;
}

.Zcircle.yellow {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px #f1c40f;
}

.Zcircle.green {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px #2ecc71;
}

.A1container {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  border-radius: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: relative;
  left: 350px;
  bottom: 275px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 70px;
}

.A1circle {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.A1circle::after {
  border-right: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  border-radius: 100%;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.A1circle.red {
  background-color: #c0392b;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px #c0392b;
}

.A1circle.yellow {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px #f1c40f;
}

.A1circle.green {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px #2ecc71;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
//first traffic light - this one works

var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".Zcircle");

for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
  myElements[i].style.opacity = 0;
}

var $15a = 2 //value which will make the light change color

if ($15a > 4) {
  var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".Zcircle");

  for (var x = 2; x < myElements.length; i++) {
    myElements[x].style.opacity = 1;
  }
} else if ($15a < 3) {
  var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".Zcircle");

  for (var x = 0; x < myElements.length; i++) {
    myElements[x].style.opacity = 1;
  }
} else {
  var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".Zcircle");

  for (var x = 1; x < myElements.length; i++) {
    myElements[x].style.opacity = 1;
  }
}

//second traffic light - this one doesnt work

var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".A1circle");

for (var a = 0; a < myElements.length; a++) {
  myElements[a].style.opacity = 0;
}

var $15b = 1; //value which will make the light change color 

if ($15b > 4) {
  var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".A1circle");

  for (var b = 2; x < myElements.length; b++) {
    myElements[b].style.opacity = 1;
  }
} else if ($15b < 3) {
  var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".A1circle");

  for (var b = 0; b < myElements.length; b++) {
    myElements[b].style.opacity = 1;
  }
} else {
  var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".A1circle");

  for (var b = 1; b < myElements.length; b++) {
    myElements[b].style.opacity = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: please use some more descriptive variable names.

Comment: Hi Nina, thank you for your reply.,  Which variables should i make more discriptive?

Comment: Your JS code is hard to read, weird vars such as $15b and $$15b.. Also if else if else if if else... I can not find the part that already works.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, i have added comments to the code. Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final code you wanted.

```
let allZCircles = select(".Zcircle"),
    allA1Circles = select(".A1Circle"),
    items = 2;

//hides all the lights
setOpacity(allZCircles, 0);
setOpacity(allA1Circles, 0);

//as per op's requirnments
if(items >= 5) {
    setOpacity(select(".Zcircle.green"), 1);  // makes green light visible
    setOpacity(select(".A1Circle.green"), 1);  // makes green light visible
} else if (items < 3) {
    setOpacity(select(".Zcircle.red"), 1);  // makes red light visible
    setOpacity(select(".A1Circle.red"), 1);  // makes red light visible
} else {
    setOpacity(select(".Zcircle.yellow"), 1);  // makes yellow light visible
    setOpacity(select(".A1Circle.yellow"), 1);  // makes yellow light visible
}


function select(selector) {return document.querySelectorAll(selector); }
function setOpacity(selectors, opacity) {selectors.forEach((selector) => selector.style.opacity = opacity);}
```

Comment: Hi Fahad, Thats really great thank you for you help! The only think i would want to change is for only one light to show at on time. So if the value for $15a = 1 only the red light would show, not all three. How might i go about doing this? Thanks again.

Comment: @jhew123 if I am getting correctly $15a and $15b means how many lights you want to show, right? if $15a is 1, then you show one light. if it is 2, you show 2 lights. right?

Comment: 15a would be the number of items on a shelf , the total being 6. So if there 5 or more on the shelf ($15a >4)  the light would be green, if then items were removed so that there were only 3 or 4, just an orange light would need to be shown to indicate it should be refilled soon, and then less then 3, it would show only a red light to indicate that it needs to be refilled asap.

Comment: Thanks for your help Fahad, I have adapeted it and got all 9 lights working perfectly!

Comment: @jhew123 glad to hear that :) just remember that there is always a simpler way to do things ;)